# What's the fastest way to get a new silver sword?

Tags: the-witcher-2

I've just begun the first chapter of the game, but I find myself... lacking.  I stabbed something big and mean with my Silver Sword as part of the Prologue, and now I'm stuck in a catch-22.

As a Witcher, most of my income comes from killing nasty things - and most of those nasty things die much faster when hit with a silver sword.  However, I am short a key ingredient to forge a new one.  I have no silver ore.  The shopkeeper will sell me some, for ~200 orens a pop (I have around 150 currently), or I can go find some.  The Witcher Wikia notes that ["some bandits"](http://witcher.wikia.com/wiki/A_Sword_for_Monsters) carry some, but isn't specific at all about how to encounter these bandits.

What's the fastest way to get enough money to buy the ore, or what's the fastest way to acquire the ore without having to kill monsters?

Comment: hmm... I seem to remember the smith selling one right off the bat, not as good as one you can craft though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By far the easiest way to earn small amounts of money is fistfighting. You can do that in Flotsam in the basement of the tavern, and you'll earn 20 orens per fight, a bit less for the first two or three. Fistfighting itself is a very easy minigame, just some quicktime events.

The mysterious merchant at the docks also sells a relatively cheap silver sword, I think it was around 200 - 250 orens. That would be an alternative to the crafted sword.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure this is applicable in your case, but the fastest way to get a silver sword is to have played the original Witcher.

You will start with a Silver Sword if you import a Witcher 1 save file, specifically, if you end the game with either [Aerondight](http://witcher.wikia.com/wiki/Aerondight), or the [Moonblade](http://witcher.wikia.com/wiki/Moon_Blade).

This saves you the trouble of having to smith a new one at the start of The Witcher 2.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 groups of bandits on the trail leading North toward the wrecked bridge and the Kayran. Defeating them should get you at least one Silver Ore. You should be able to save up enough Orens for the second ore through pilfering houses or arm wrestling.

Answer (score 1):

To anyone else wondering how to get a new sword my advice is to wait until you infiltrate Loredo's estate. Sneaking about the back you'll find a diagram for 'robust silver sword' which is marginally better than the standard blade. Also if you find yourself lacking silver you can find enough in then nearby caves at the dock, just watch out for Nekkers.